# "Viper4android" removed "Audiofx" app permanently

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, equalizer

***To save time, you can just read the bold writing OR the short summary at the end***

I saw some reviews of "*Viper4Android*", it looked good so **I installed it on my OnePlus One** (CM13 NOT CM13S). **The tutorial I followed was in the description of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lUFtqY8JtQ) YouTube video**. **I flashed the *viper4android* zip file** (which I downloaded from the tutorial video) in TWRP recovery, in the zip file name it said "*lolli*" meaning lollipop which isn't the android version I use but apparently all I needed to do for it to work on Marshmallow was enabled init.d and create a file named "*08setperm*" to the init.d directory created when init.d was enabled.

**I followed all the steps of the written text tutorial** **but after I rebooted my phone as the last step,** **the *viper4android* app wasn't making any changes**, so after some looking around the app and on the internet for ways to make it work, I concluded that I simply couldn't use it on my device.

I began uninstalling it by **first uninstalling the drivers in the app itself**. Then **I undone the changes I made in the "Universal Init.d" App and deleted everything in that app that I could.** I uninstalled "Universal Init.d" when this was complete.

I rebooted the phone and tested the *viper4android* app to make sure it didn't just magically start working and it didn't so I closed it and **used Titanium Backup to uninstall it as it was installed as a system app.**

After I rebooted my phone once again, to clear the ram of any evidence of viper4android, *I noticed that the "AudioFX" app was gone.* I had planned on going back to using that app again as an equalizer since viper4android wasn't working.

**I flashed a zip I found somewhere on XDA which was the AudioFX app for CM13**, upon opening the app, it would remain blank with only the title bar reading "AudioFX". **So it basically wasn't functional.**

I then tried **updating to the latest build (CM13 nightlies) using CyanDelta**, I had the latest update downloaded and I then let **CyanDelta automatically flash the zip** along with romracers v80 xposed framework zip and then clear the cache etc.

After it was completely booted, I noticed **the AudioFX app was still missing**. I will continue to flash the latest nightly builds until the audiofx app is reinstalled from them.

**The point is, *viper4android* completely removed the *audiofx* app from my phone and I can't get it back even if I flash the latest nightly build of CM13. Right now I am flashing a nightly build straight from cyanogenmod downloads that hasn't been messed with by CyanDelta as a test.**

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TWRP, do an advanced wipe on all but internal storage.  Then freshly flash CyanogenMod.

Comment: This is correct.  CyanDelta only flashes the changes, so if AudioFX was in a previous version then it won't be flashed as part of a newer version.  OP needs to flash the entire ROM.